# When I can say a dataset is imbalanced?

Tags: validation, unbalanced-classes

I have a data set with only two outputs: positive and negative

The ratio of positive:negative is 3.5:1

In this case, is my data set unbalanced?

If so, what metric I should use to report the performance of classification on this data set? I intend to use: AUC, Precision and Accuracy (with a note that the baseline accuracy is 3.5/4.5 = 0.77).

Is this okay?

Thank you very much